# Excel 2013 Date time difference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column with date and time for start (IN) and end (OUT) and I want to calculate the difference in days.

```
Date:  IN   Time:  IN   Date:  OUT  Time:  OUT
24/07/2018  12:15:00    26/07/2018  06:11:00
```

I combine them into date time IN and OUT by using:

```
E1=TEXT(A2,"dd/mm/yy ")&TEXT(B2,"hh:mm:ss")
F1=TEXT(C2,"dd/mm/yy ")&TEXT(D2,"hh:mm:ss")
```

But I am unable to find any working code for the difference in number of hours.

Answer (score 2):

`TEXT` will convert your dates and times into text (strangely enough).

Adding the date and time will return a date/time value so you could use:
`=SUM(C2:D2)-SUM(A2:B2)` to return `1.74722222`
(**edit:** if you then give the cell a custom number format of `d:h:mm` it will display `1:17:56` or 1 day, 17 hours, 56 minutes).

(**EDIT AGAIN**:  Sorry, only just seen you want it in hours.  Give the cell a custom number format of `[hh]:mm`.  The square brackets tells it to count over 24 hours.  This will return `41:56`).

or

`=DATEDIF(SUM(A2:B2),SUM(C2:D2),"d")` to return `2`.

or if you just want days from the dates you could just use
`=C2-A2` to return `2`.

Dates and times in Excel are just numbers - no need to complicate things by turning them to text.

Answer (score 1):

```
= (F1 - E1) * 24
```

Rather easly :)

Comment: You could also use [DATEDIF()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c). Example `=DATEDIF(E5,E6,"D")`

Comment: `41.93` isn't a date/time.  It's in decimal - 0.93 is 55.8 minutes.